# twitter activity feed not working

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

For the project I am loading **icimod twitter** dynamically (only when twitter is called I load the twitter).My code is:

```
function _twitter_data(pos, type, hover, showimg,stat, controllerId){
        var parents = $('input#'+pos).parents('div.wrapitem');
        parents.find('div.description').html('Processing...').fadeIn();
        var url = 'assets/scripts/twitter.js';
        $.getScript(url)
            .done(function(){
               parents.find('div.item').append('<div class="description disp hover"><a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/icimod"  data-widget-id="374478558938148864">Tweets by @icimod</a></div>'); 

            });
   }
```

In **twitter.js** I have following:

```
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

Now when I load the twitter in console it gives the following error:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//E
```

in http://platform.twitter.com/widget.js

The only thing that shows up is the link: Tweets by **@icimod**

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong? Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not actually sure but I think the problem is due to blocking of Twitter in my PC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the widget in question was built for v1 of the Twitter timeline. Last I was aware, that has been officially shutdown, as noted here: https://dev.twitter.com/blog/planning-for-api-v1-retirement. I believe what you're getting is a 410 response, rather than JSON data. I'd suggest examining the response in Firebug or similar to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

Also adbock plus blocks twitter widget(doesn't show up) on Firefox. I just figured this out today. I disabled the plugin and everything worked fine!